# Does Zepto support passing data to event handlers like jQuery?

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, zepto

or rather: can I write code that allows passing data to event handlers that runs on both Zepto and jQuery (e.g. like Zurb's Foundation should)?

Having an event handler that needs external data defined at time of declaration, this data can be passed as part of the `event.data` in jQuery:

```
var name = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
// add click function
$(this).click({_name: name}, function(event) {
    $("#"+event.data._name).val($(this).find("a").attr("value"));
    return(false);
});
```

Similar doesn't seem possible in Zepto. How can the same be achieved and how does code need to look that runs on both Zepto and jQuery for this use case?

Comment: According to [this pull request](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/pull/183) and as well as [this](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/issues/143) it should be possible. I admit I have not tried it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using Zepto's `$.proxy` function, see http://zeptojs.com/#changelog. `$.proxy` is compatible between Zepto and jQuery.

Example:

```
$.proxy(function(json) {
    ...

    // store
    data[this._channel] = json;
}, {_channel: channel})
```